# How to display PDF files from remote location on UIWebView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to display a pdf file, using an iOS app, that is located on our website. Here's how I'm doing this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("preparing segue")
        if segue.identifier == "PdfWebView" {

            print("Found segue")

            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PdfViewController

            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            let row = myIndexPath.row


            //Pass selected cell title to next View
            detailViewController.website = pdfLinks[row]

            print("Website: ", detailViewController.website)
        }
    }
```

`// This is on pdfViewController`
`// The webiste = http://www.example.com/some-pdf-document-to-display.pdf`

```
if let website = website {
    print("Getting pdf: ",website)

    if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(website, withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil){

        print(pdf)   // <-- this is always nil
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)

        webView.loadRequest(req)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? Needless to say, this is my very first app that I'm developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is not in your app you should not use NSBundle.

```
let pdfUrl = NSURL(string: website)
let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfUrl)
```

I'm also not sure why you are adding the webView subview to the view. Shouldn't that be done somewhere else? Shouldn't you push a controller with the webview instead?

Comment: That worked. This is what I wanted. Disregard the webView inside subview. I was gasping to figure out anything I could, and I was just trying to see if that's why it didn't show up. I removed it now.

Answer (score 3):

File is not in your Bundle. Instead you can directly load the URL.

```
 let website = "http://www.sanface.com/pdf/test.pdf"
 let reqURL =  NSURL(string: website)
 let request = NSURLRequest(URL: reqURL!)

 webView.loadRequest(request)
```